# formula to search rows then allocate specific name from another table

Tags: excel, formula

I have a spreadsheet that is pulling in call survey data and set up as follows

- Main sheet is called 'Data'
- In the main sheet, columns F,G,H,I hold agent ID numbers dependant on what agents worked on this specific call through it's journey to end. All agent numbers start with the prefix either of 146,144 or 145.

so for example 1st agent 14400 took the call then transferred to agent 14600 then that one onto agent 14500.

Sheet 2 is called 'Teams'

Column A holds agent ID's
Column B is team name

What i want to be able to put a formula in column A of the sheet 'Data' which will then search through rows until it finds a number begining 146.

Once it has found this number it will then search the sheet 'teams' and allocate the required team manager name from column C.

Hope this all makes sense but please let me know if not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution (I tested it on your spreadsheet):

`=VLOOKUP(SUMPRODUCT(--(F2:I2>=146000),--(F2:I2<=146999),F2:I2),Teams!A:C,3,FALSE)`

- `--(F2:I2>=146000)` return an array with 0 or 1, 1 if the value is greater than 146000, `--(F2:I2<=146999)` same but 1 if value less than 146999
- `SUMPRODUCT` is a logical and between the three array that return the value 146xxx. to know more [sumproduct](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/10/excel-sumproduct-formula/)
- VLOOKUP search in the first column of the range A:C on the Teams' sheet for the id and return the content of the third column.
- If you want to have a custom result if the 146xxx is not present in the row you have to use `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(..),"TEXT_TO_SHOW")`

Comment: I'll  give  this a try when I get a chance and let you know. Looks logical though so fingers crossed.

Comment: ok have tried what you suggested and unfortunately it returns #N/A. I have uploaded a sheet to my one drive for you to look at if easier. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?page=view&resid=A8316808DCB54154!112&authkey=!AE3TDhGMsa7Ay_M

Comment: I changed the answer with the correct solutions, you can see it in your spreadsheet on google drive.